# Has wamp server special setting for xajax

Tags: wampserver, xajax

I change my wamp server.I understand that my old xajax project does not work. I want to know that Has xajax special setting on wamp server?

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer is basically Apache/PHP/MySQL so only whatever is required to run on Apache/PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how old is your xajax project and what version of xajax did you use, 0.6 ? In former times I have had the same problem as I changed the php Version. If you use the old 0.5 Version of xajax upgrade on 0.6. And debug your code with firebug and take a look at the php warnings and errors. The problems lie in the use of xajax.